# How to order data set in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataset

I have a data frame like this:

```
dataset <- data.frame(COL1 = c(1,2,3,4), COL2 = c(4,3,2,1))
```

I'm then trying to order it like so:

```
dataset <- dataset[order(-COl1),]
```

However, this results in an error because apparently COL1 doesn't exist:

```
Error in order(-COl1) : object 'COl1' not found
```

If I change the declaration of the dataset to:

```
dataset <- data.frame(COL1 <- c(1,2,3,4), COL2 <- c(4,3,2,1))
```

It works fine! However, the problem is that the dataset declaration is generated by another program so i cannot change it. Is there a way to re-declare the data set in a way that will allow me to order it properly?

Comment: You could use `with` or `$` `dataset[with(dataset, order(-COL1)),]`.  BTW, you didn't have a column `COl1`, it is `COL1` (perhaps a typo)

Comment: @akrun Perfect! That worked - thanks for the prompt answer. If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: an alternative might be `library(dplyr); dataset <- arrange(dataset, desc(COL1))`or incl `library(magrittr); dataset %<>% arrange(desc(COL1))` but here of course this is too much overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with` or `$`, `[`, i.e.

```
dataset[with(dataset, order(-COL1)),]
```

Or

```
dataset[order(-dataset$COL1),]
```

Or

```
dataset[order(-dataset['COL1']),]
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(dataset), -COL1)
```